# Search in Two Categories

Tags: search

I want to search in two categories without using the search box at all.

So far, I have this code to display the desired categories,

```
<?php wp_dropdown_categories('child_of=3&hierarchical=1&depth=1&hide_empty=0&name=cat[one]'); ?>
<?php wp_dropdown_categories('exclude=3&hierarchical=1&depth=1&hide_empty=0&name=cat[two]'); ?>
```

I have names as array cat as I wanted them to GET from URL and build custom query. I have tried many things but failed.

I just want the user to just press search and it should display posts that are in "Both" categories.

Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Basically you don't really want search, but separate page that will list post on specific condition?

You can create [template for a page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages) with [Loop](http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop) that will query for posts, belonging to both categories, using [`category__and` parameter](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts#Category_Parameters).

Comment: ok, great suggestion, I did it and its what I needed. Thanks again.